# Click event lost after rerendering react (caused by blur event)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-glitter-zuvr8?file=/src/App.js

I have a section with a text input and a button

I want to refresh the section on blur event of text input (I force refresh with key attribute in my example)
and display a text on click event on the button

The issue : When the focus is on the input text and I click on the button, I have the blur event and the click event at same time.

The click event is ignored.
I thinks the is because the order of JS events are blur, then click.

To reproduce :

No focus on input text, then click on the button => OK

Focus on input text, then click beside on the page, then click on the button => OK

Focus on input text, then click then click on the button => Not OK (the text "clicked" is not displayed)  (but with a second click => OK)

Comment: You can use `onMouseUp` instead of `onClick`

Comment: Yes, the order is not the same with onMouseUp or onMouseDown. But I want to keep the onClick because external components are using click events

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Any advice?

Comment: Same here, encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep the 'click' event instead of replacing it with 'mouseup', you can do the following inside your 'blur' event handler:

```
if (event?.relatedTarget instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
  event.relatedTarget.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unfortunate mixture of features that together cause this *lost update*.
If you refrain from forcing a refresh via `<div key={this.state.numberOfBlur}>` everything works as expected.

As far as I understood the issue:

- changing `key` throws away the existing DOM elements and replaces them with new ones
- Click events are only triggered if the `mouseDown` and the `mouseUp` events originate on the same DOM node

The chain of events here is:

- `mouseDown` removed the focus from the input
- this fires a `blur` event
- the `blur` event triggers a callback
- the callback updates the state with a new value for `numberOfBlur`
- the component is re-rendered
- the key changed because of `numberOfBlur` changed
- the existing DOM nodes are replaced by new DOM nodes
- the `mouseUp` event originates on a new DOM node
- thus no `click` event is formed